# Does positive canonical bundle imply general type for surfaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a minimal smooth projective surface (over an alg. closed field of characteristic 0). Does $K_X^2 > 0$ imply that $X$ is of general type? (i.e., has kodaira dimension 2).

This seems to follow from the Enriques-Kodaira classification, but wikipedia seems to shy away from making this exact statement. Is it true?

If so references would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried projective plane?